# When the Plantuml file is of 10K lines, Not able to generate the complete image rather only half the image is generated

Tags: uml, plantuml, tool-uml

I download the plantuml jar from the link : http://plantuml.com/de/download

It is able to generate the image as png successfully for the Plantuml content

But when the size of the plantuml content is above 10K lines, It is able to generate only half the content and remaining is not showing in the image

Could someone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Harry

Comment: I now see that the question has been cross posted to Plantuml forum (https://forum.plantuml.net/10068/plantuml-lines-generate-complete-image-rather-image-generated) and got an accepted answer regarding the setting of PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE (see http://plantuml.com/faq )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's already answered elsewhere (see above comment).

Answer (score 0):

As shown at https://forum.plantuml.net/10068/plantuml-lines-generate-complete-image-rather-image-generated and the FAQ at https://plantuml.com/faq#e689668a91b8d065
the solution is to define `PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE` environment variable, or pass it in on the java command:

```bash
java -DPLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE=8192 -jar /path/to/plantuml.jar ...
```

You can also try to `scale 0.3` (or some other factor) to "zoom out" (although this doesn't always prevent clipping).